# What's a good regex to remove extraneous characters from the end of a string?

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regex to remove the characters at the end of a string that aren't needed, but may be present earlier in the string (which is expected and good).

Here's an example which should resolve to "CARVER HOUSE - KITCHEN"

```
CARVER HOUSE - KITCHEN(
CARVER HOUSE - KITCHEN[
CARVER HOUSE - KITCHEN - (
CARVER HOUSE - KITCHEN :
```

Here's another example that should resolve to "CARVER HOUSE : (NIGHT)[N1] -  KITCHEN"

```
CARVER HOUSE : (NIGHT)[N1] -  KITCHEN(
CARVER HOUSE : (NIGHT)[N1] -  KITCHEN[
CARVER HOUSE : (NIGHT)[N1] -  KITCHEN - (
CARVER HOUSE : (NIGHT)[N1] -  KITCHEN :
```

So basically, the last letter or number should be found and everything else is whacked off.

Also, I'm not looking for a big messy method that goes character by character to find the last alphanumeric. This should really be possible to do in a line or two of code.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Tried something like `"\W+$"` for "non-word-char at end of string"?

Comment: @Reimeus I have tried a few things, but they weren't pretty (at all). I was considering reversing the string to see if that worked any better, then reversing it back, but that seemed messy too.

Comment: `"[^0-9a-zA-Z]*$"` will locate the trailing string. Then you can either get substring the part you want, or remove the trailing part. What language are you using?

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks! That worked perfectly.

Comment: Can't you be a little more specific? And please note that a regex in general _does not have_ to match all the input text; it only has to match what is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a regex like `\W+$` to find non-word-characters at the end of the string and replace those.

```
String s = "CARVER HOUSE : (NIGHT)[N1] -  KITCHEN - (";
s = s.replaceAll("\\W+$", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

Result is `CARVER HOUSE : (NIGHT)[N1] -  KITCHEN`